# Google Apps Script: Activate and sort rows when cells in given column are not blank

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script

I'm extremely new to Apps Script and trying to make my first thing. It's a shopping list.

I want to create a function that will activate and then sort (by Column 1, 'Aisle #') all rows where there are values in a given other column (Column 3, 'Qty'). The idea is to sort the items on the list for that week (i.e., with a value filled in for Qty) by aisle to give me the order I should be looking for things. I do not want to sort items which are in the spreadsheet but without
a value for Qty.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var rangeVals = range.getValues()
  
function orderList2(){
  
 if(rangeVals[3] != ""){
  sheet.activate().sort(1, ascending=true);
    };
  };
```

I'm trying to use "if" to define which rows to activate before doing the sort (as I don't want to sort the entire sheet—I only want to sort the items I will be buying that week, i.e., the items with a value in Column 3). The script runs but ends up sorting the entire sheet.

The closest thing I could find was an iteration, but when I did it, it ended up only activating the top-left cell.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

Use [Range.sort()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj) instead of [Sheet.sort()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#sort(Integer,Boolean)) if you don't want to sort the entire sheet.

#### Explanation:

You want to sort the data according to the value in column A (`Aisle #`), if the corresponding value in C (`Qty`) is not empty.

If my assumption is correct, the rows where `Qty` is empty should go below the rest of data, and they should not be sorted according to their `Aisle #`.

In this case, I'd suggest the following:

1. Sort the full range of data (headers excluded) according to `Qty`, so that the rows without a `Qty` are placed at the bottom, using `Range.sort()` (if you don't need to exclude the headers, you can use `Sheet.sort()` instead).
2. Use [SpreadsheetApp.flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush()) to apply the sort to the spreadsheet.
3. Use [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()), [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) to know how many rows in the initial range have their column C populated (variable `QtyElements` in the sample below).
4. Using `QtyElements`, retrieve the range of rows with a non-empty column C, and sort it according to column 1, using `Range.sort()`.

#### Code sample:

```
function orderList2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var firstRow = 2; // Range starts at row 2, header row excluded
  var fullRange = sheet.getRange(firstRow, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  fullRange.sort(3); // Sort full range according to Qty
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Refresh spreadsheet
  var QtyElements = fullRange.getValues().filter(row => row[2] !== "").length;
  sheet.getRange(firstRow, 1, QtyElements, sheet.getLastColumn())
       .sort(1); // If not specified, default ascending: true
       //.sort({column: 1, ascending: false}); // Uncomment if you want descending sort
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Range.sort(sortSpecObj)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj)

Comment: Hi, @lamblichus thanks so much for getting back to me!

Unfortunately, this code still seems to sort the whole sheet according to Column A. 

Interestingly, if I run the below function first to sort the data and THEN run your code (without the fullRange.sort(3) or SpreadsheetApp.flush()), then it sorts the whole sheet by Column A, BUT the ones that are populated for Qty are kept together. 

'function getList() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D2:D').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().sort(4, true);
};'

Lmk if you have any ideas!

Comment: @lamblichus

Interestingly, I got this to do what I wanted it to by changing the filter to

.filter(row => row[3] !== "")

I thought that Column C was supposed to be designated by '2' though?

Also, could you explain the elements inside of the function .filter? (e.g., what does => mean? I've just copied what you have but don't fully understand it).

Thanks heaps!

Comment: @NicholasFung That's very strange. Arrays are 0-indexed, so in this case `row[2]` refers to the value in column C. I can't reproduce this, the code I provided is working for me, no change required. About `=>`, see [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: @lamblichus Yeah that's what I thought too. Thanks very much in any case for your help, and for pointing me in the direction of understanding arrow functions!